# How can I create a column that flags when another datetime column has changed date?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How can I create a column 'Marker that flags (0 or 1) when another datetime column 'DT' has changed date?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Obs']=float_array
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_array)
df['Marker'] = 0
print(type(df['DT'].dt))
```

<class 'pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties'>

```
df['Marker'] = df.where(datetime.date(df.DT.dt) == datetime.date(df.DT.shift(1).dt),1)
```

TypeError: an integer is required (got type DatetimeProperties)

Comment: Is possible add some sample data, 2-3 rows with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for convert to dates and for convert `True/False` to `1/0` is used [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Marker'] = (df.DT.dt.date == df.DT.dt.date.shift()).view('i1')
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Marker'] = np.where(df.DT.dt.date == df.DT.dt.date.shift(), 0, 1)
```